# Twitter Bootstrap Sharing layout across multiple pages of the application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to develop a simple app with plain HTML and Twitter bootsrap. I would like to get some pointers on sharing the common layout across multiple HTML pages of the same app.

My app has a home page, then Page1, Page2 and Page3. All the pages have the same header, footer and side nav bar. I don't want to repeat that code in all the pages. I am trying to get something similar to the master page-child pages of Asp.Net.

What should be the approch here? Does anybody have any suggestions on a best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the lack of server-side processing, use client side templating, like mustache.js. In your case, each of the header, footer, side nav bar would be a mustache template that you can insert in each page.